# How to call C function from R?

Tags: c, r

How can you use some function written in C from R level using R data.
eg. to use function like:

```
double* addOneToVector(int n, const double* vector) {
    double* ans = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ans[i] = vector[i] + 1
    return ans;
}
```

in the context:

```
x = 1:3
x = addOneToVector(x)
x # 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've searched stackoverflow first but I noticed there is no answer for that in here.
The general idea is (commands for linux, but same idea under other OS):

1. Create function that will only take pointers to basic types and do everything by side-effects (returns void). eg in a file called `foo.c`:

   ```
   void addOneToVector(int* n, double* vector) {
       for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i)
           vector[i] += 1.0;
   }
   ```
2. Compile file C source as dynamic library, you can use R shortcut to do this:

   ```
   $ R CMD SHLIB foo.c
   ```

   This will then create a file called `foo.so` on Mac or `foo.dll` on Windows.
3. Load dynamic library from R

   on Mac:

   ```
   dyn.load("foo.so")
   ```

   or on Windows:

   ```
   dyn.load("foo.dll")
   ```
4. Call C functions using `.C` R function, IE:

   ```
   x = 1:3
   ret_val = .C("addOneToVector", n=length(x), vector=as.double(x))
   ```

It returns list from which you can get value of inputs after calling functions eg.

```
ret_val$x # 2, 3, 4
```

You can now wrap it to be able to use it from R easier.

There is a nice page describing whole process with more details here (also covering Fortran):

[http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egeyer/rc/)

Comment: Package "inline" is, also, convenient on this context: `addOne = inline::cfunction(sig = c(n = "integer", vector = "numeric"), body = 'for(int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) vector[i] += 1.0;', convention = ".C")` and then `addOne(length(x), as.double(x))$vector`.

Comment: Would like to mention that upon using this method I noticed the following. `foo.so` is created in Mac, while on Windows the appropriate file is `foo.dll`

Answer (score 3):

I just did the same thing in a very simple way using the [Rcpp package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html). It allows you to write C++ functions directly in R.

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction("
NumericVector addOneToVector(NumericVector vector) {
  int n = vector.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    vector[i] = vector[i] + 1.0;

  return vector;
}")
```

Find more details here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html. C++ functions can be done very fast with these instructions.

Comment: why not postfix increment? that is i++ instead of ++i?

Comment: I wanted to use the code of the OP with as little changes as possible to show how simple it is to use C++ inside R with the Rcpp package.

Comment: since the increment is performed at the bottom of the loop it doesn't matter.
i++ has a higher rate of use.
I'll ask odd questions if I want to. That's how I learn. Even ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I wanted to thank both @m0nhawk and @Jan for their immensely useful contributions to this problem.

I tried both methods on my MacBook: first the one showed m0nhawk which requires creating a function in C (without the main method) and then compiling using `R CMD SHLIB <prog.c>` and then invoking the function from R using the .C command

Here's a small C code I wrote (not a pro in C - just learning in bits and pieces)

Step 1: Write the C Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func_test() {
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("The value of i is: %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Step 2: Compile the program using

```
R CMD SHLIB func_test.c
```

This will produce a func_test.so file

Step 3: Now write the R Code that invokes this C function from within R Studio

```
dyn.load("/users/my_home_dir/xxx/ccode/ac.so")
.C("func_test")
```

Step 4: Output:

> > .C("func_test") The value of i is: 0 The value of i is: 1 The value of i is: 2 The value of i is: 3 The value of i is: 4 list()

Then I tried the direct method suggested by Jan - using the RCpp package

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction("
NumericVector addOneToVector(NumericVector vector) {
  int n = vector.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    vector[i] = vector[i] + 1.0;

  return vector;
}")

# Test code to test the function
addOneToVector(c(1,2,3))
```

Both methods worked superbly. I can now start writing functions in C or C++ and use them in R

Thank you once again!