# Optimize functions in C using Genetic Algorithms in R

Tags: r

I need to optimize some functions that are in the C language, but using genetic algorithms packages in R.

Is there any way to call C functions in R?

In matlab I know that there is this possibility through "mex". Is there something similar in R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call C function from R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026818/how-to-call-c-function-from-r)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to call `C` functions in `R`. Have a look at `.C()` and `.Call()` and `.External()` and most of all at the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual.