# How to call the main function of a c code using R?

Tags: c, r, r-package

I'm trying to create an R package that uses this code:
[c code](https://github.com/amamory/seriation/blob/master/cfm-seriation.c)

I searched how to do this and tried the following ways:

1 - Using the inline package.

```
# orderer ####

#' Orderer
#'
#' @export

orderer <- function(associationPreprocessed){
  if(!is.character(associationPreprocessed)){
    stop("Error, the argument 'associationPreprocessed' must be of type 'character'")
  }
  code <- paste0(readLines("src/cfm-seriation.c"), collapse = "\n")
  cfm <- inline::cfunction(signature(argc = "integer", argv = "character"),
                           body = code,
                           language = "C", convention = ".C",
                           libargs = c("-lm", "-lpthread", "-lrt"),
                           includes = c("#include <stdio.h>", "#include <time.h>",
                                        "#include <math.h>", "#include <stdlib.h>",
                                        "#include <string.h>"))
  cfm(1L, paste0("f=", associationPreprocessed))
  return (NULL)
}
```

I stripped out all the header information of the c code to use this code snippet.

The idea was to pass the path for the data, [Escherichia coli](https://github.com/amamory/seriation/blob/master/data/Escherichia_coli.dat), using the argument `associationPreprocessed`.

2 - Using the `.C()` function to call `main`, with the `useDynLib(pkg)` to dynamically load the `.so` lib. Similar to the example of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026818/how-to-call-c-function-from-r).

I believe I got closer to achieving what I expected using the `inline::cfuntion()`, but I still haven't figured out how to do what I want.

All the examples that I've seen use a simple c code, with only one function.

Comment: Your question is a lot to address (you've tried many different things) - but a few things I noticed. The first is that according to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/inline/versions/0.3.14/topics/cfunction) you need to strip out all of the header information in the body (so just reading in that github source is not going to work). I also think this is relevant: "To declare multiple functions in the same library one can use `setCMethod` supplying lists of signatures and implementations. In this case, provide as many method names in `f` as you define methods."

Comment: I forgot to describe that, sorry. I removed the headers of the c code and manually added them as the includes argument of inline::cfunction. I will try to break the code into multiple functions and use setCmethod, thank you.

Comment: Good luck! It does seem like a complicated task - I'm not sure how you address the need to sometimes have multiple intermediary functions to power a single end function. To address the question in your title though  - if you look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026818/how-to-call-c-function-from-r) and the comment on the answer, it appears you do not need to invoke `main()` to use your function

Comment: The `main()` function is special in C.  It's the program entry point for the language and should only be called from the C-runtime initialization code which contains the entry point for the executable.  How often will your R program call into this code?  If only once, then just run the program from R.  In C we call that a `system()` or `exec()` call, R must have an equivalent.